# How to count the number of tabs need to cover a string

Tags: java, string, itext

I am trying to create a string by arranging my data in two columns.

```
        String s = "";
        List selectedItems = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        s = s + (String) selectedItems.get(0);
        String t;
        for (int i = 1 ; i<selectedItems.size();i++){
            t = (String) selectedItems.get(i);
            if (i%2!=0){
                s = s + "\t\t\t";
            }
            else{
                s = s + "\n";
            }
                s = s + (String) t;
        }
```

My idea is to use a code like this for the task. but depending on the length of the strings, I can't get the second column to one line.

I am thinking there is a way to count the number of tabs need to cover one string an change the number of extra tabs I add instead of adding 3 tabs to every line. but I can't figure out how to count this.

how can I fix this problem?

current results:

```
one     two
three     four
five    six
```

expected results:

```
one     two
three   four
five    six
```

this is the result of after fill the string with " " with a total length of 30.

[image]

i am only using jfx to get the data. itextPdf us used to write the string to a pdf

Comment: Warning: you are using the raw type `List`. **Never use raw types.** Always provide the necessary type arguments, e.g. `List<String>`. That'll also make your type casts unnecessary.

Comment: that function returns a list of "Objects", anyway, thanks, but that is not the issue here.

Comment: no idea why someone would vote close to without a comment

Comment: Have you considered using spaces instead of tabs? It will be much easier to count how much spaces you need. Besides, tab does not have a fixed length. It might be configured to be 2 or 3 or 4 or even more spaces depending on your editor.

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans I thought about using space. but the space occupied by each letter is different. so even having the same number of characters does not help the issue.

Comment: I suggest you to post a screenshot to a question. Additionally -  if you can't solve it with spaces - tabs won't help you. The problem is with font you are using. You need to use font where all letters occupy same width or, depending where you're printing text, calculate the width of text and print text with offset in pixels.

Comment: Are you using JavaFX? Please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired output you don't need to count anything - you just use `System.out.printf`:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s\n", "test", "test1");
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s\n", "longertest", "test2");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
test       test1     
longertest test2
```

As was mentioned in the comment - that will not fix a problem if the font that you use is not monospaced, so I would suggest changing the font as well.

```java
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
```

Comment: As you can see in the image in the question, the font used appears top be a proportional one. Your routine relies on the font being monospace, though.

Comment: @mki that's a good point. But spaces will not be a solution in this case anyway

Comment: Agreed. Not a satisfactory one at least.

Answer (score 0):

Accordin to [this](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-5-legacy/how-format-string-resulting-two-column-display) document you have 3 options:

Assuming you have such data:

```
public static final String[][] DATA = {
    {"John Edward Jr.", "AAA"},
    {"Pascal Einstein W. Alfi", "BBB"},
};
```

1: use a table

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidthPercentage(50);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{5, 1});
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    table.addCell("Name: " + DATA[0][0]);
    table.addCell(DATA[0][1]);
    table.addCell("Surname: " + DATA[1][0]);
    table.addCell(DATA[1][1]);
    table.addCell("School: " + DATA[2][0]);
    table.addCell(DATA[1][1]);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

2: use tabs

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    document.add(createParagraphWithTab("Name: ", DATA[0][0], DATA[0][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithTab("Surname: ", DATA[1][0], DATA[1][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithTab("School: ", DATA[2][0], DATA[2][1]));
    document.close();
}

public Paragraph createParagraphWithTab(String key, String value1, String value2) {
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(200f));
    p.add(key);
    p.add(value1);
    p.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    p.add(value2);
    return p;
}
```

3: use spaces and a monospaced font

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
    document.add(createParagraphWithSpaces(font, String.format("%s: %s", "Name", DATA[0][0]), DATA[0][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithSpaces(font, String.format("%s: %s", "Surname", DATA[1][0]), DATA[1][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithSpaces(font, String.format("%s: %s", "School", DATA[2][0]), DATA[2][1]));
    document.close();
}

public Paragraph createParagraphWithSpaces(Font font, String value1, String value2) {
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.setFont(font);
    p.add(String.format("%-35s", value1));
    p.add(value2);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: this seems like an answer, but this problem is a part of a much bigger system and i simply cant change the data type that i can give to text pdf, I can only give one string

Comment: @Eshaka if your routine is only a part of a bigger system, then there must be some contract, some definition, how your return data is to be interpreted. If this contract only says "the return string is somehow added to the pdf" without any information allowing you to estimate the resulting format, then you cannot create such columns. Thus, you have to communicate with the team whose code calls your code or the system architect and discuss options for you to estimate the resulting layout.